# PHP Add to Cart - how to create array?

Tags: php, arrays

I can't understand how to do this. This is my add to cart script:

```
$_SESSION['sku'] = $_POST['sku'];
$_SESSION['quantity'] = $_POST['quantity'];

$_SESSION['cart'][] = array($_SESSION['sku'] => $_SESSION['quantity']);

foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $sku => $quantity) {
    echo $sku . ":" . $quantity "<br/>";
}
```

This echos back things like this:

```
2:Array
3:Array
4:Array
5:Array
```

I think I am building `$_SESSION['cart']` correctly, yes? I just don't understand how to echo them back properly.

EDIT:
var_dump of $_SESSION after playing around with it for a bit:

```
array(3) { ["sku"]=> &string(3) "503" ["quantity"]=> &string(1) "2" ["cart"]=> &array(17) { [0]=> array(1) { [506]=> string(1) "4" } [1]=> array(1) { [505]=> string(1) "2" } [2]=> array(1) { [505]=> string(1) "2" } [3]=> array(1) { [505]=> string(1) "2" } [4]=> array(1) { [505]=> string(1) "2" } [5]=> array(1) { [505]=> string(1) "2" } [6]=> array(1) { [505]=> string(1) "2" } [7]=> array(1) { [505]=> string(1) "2" } [8]=> array(1) { [505]=> string(1) "2" } [9]=> array(1) { [505]=> string(1) "2" } [10]=> array(1) { [506]=> string(0) "" } [11]=> array(1) { [505]=> string(1) "2" } [12]=> array(1) { [505]=> string(1) "2" } [13]=> array(1) { [503]=> string(1) "2" } [14]=> array(1) { [503]=> string(1) "2" } [15]=> array(1) { [503]=> string(1) "2" } [16]=> array(1) { [503]=> string(1) "2" } } }
```

Comment: what's **var_dump()** of **$_SESSION** ?

Comment: Use `<pre>` with `print_r()` for readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array looks like:

```
cart = Array(n){
         [0]=>  array(1){ ['SKU1'] => int(Quantity1)},
         [1]=>  array(1){ ['SKU2'] => int(Quantity2)},
...
}
```

so you should actually use it like this:

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $arr) {
    foreach($arr as $sku => $quantity) {
        echo $sku . ":" . $quantity . "<br/>";
    }    
}
```

Or, you can add the SKUs to the cart like this:

```
$sku = $_SESSION['sku'];
$quantity = $_SESSION['quantity']);
$_SESSION['cart'][$sku] = $quantity;
```

and then you'll be able to use your code "as is":

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $sku => $quantity) {
    echo $sku . ":" . $quantity "<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are doing it correctly. How you want to see result?

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$_SESSION['sku']] = $_SESSION['quantity'];
```

to use just the one `foreach`